# I need to show and hide an object through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched thoroughly and read many of the questions on the same subject in here, however, none of them seemed to help with my issue.
  I need to show a textbox for the user to inform the reason for impediment, but only when the option "Impeded" is selected in the combobox.
  Here is my code:

```
<tr>
  <td class="titulos">Status:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <SELECT class=caixas id=cbostatus style="WIDTH: 3cm;" tabIndex=25 name=cbostatus onselect= "StatusTest();">   
        <option selected></option>
        <option value "Opened">Opened</option>
        <option value "Started">Started</option>
        <option value "Not Concluded">Not Concluded</option>
        <option value "Concluded">Concluded</option>
        <option value "Impeded">Impeded</option>
    </SELECT>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And it is calling the JavaScript function "StatusTest", which reads like so:

```
if (document.getElementById('cbostatus').options[cbostatus.selectedIndex].value == "Impeded"){
    // show
    document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'block';
} else {
    // hide
    document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'none';
}
```

With "ImpReason" being the textbox that i want to hide or show. I got much of this code from here, however, it doesnt work. If there is anything wrong with the question please tell me, so i can ask it properly, since i really really need an answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Are the equal signs between the `value` attributes and their values also missing from your actual markup?

Comment: Try `onchange` instead of `onselect`

Comment: Use onchange event and don't look up options. Just test the value of the select directly. `if (document.getElementById('cbostatus').value == 'Impeded') {`, etc.

Comment: You could do easier using jquery funtion show and hide http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi which equal signs? sorry if its a noobie question

Comment: Your options aren't written correctly. Should be in the form `<option value="someValue">Text</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need and equals sign after your `value` attributes:

`value="Opened"`

You need to change `onSelect` to `onChange`

I also added a span tag with `ImpReason` because it wasn't included in the example.

Here is the jsfiddle showing it:

https://jsfiddle.net/hh4xy9v7/

```
<tr>
  <td class="titulos">Status:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <select class="caixas" id="cbostatus" style="WIDTH: 3cm;" 
    tabIndex="25" name="cbostatus" onChange="StatusTest()">   
                            <option selected></option>
                            <option value="Opened">Opened</option>
                            <option value="Started">Started</option>
                            <option value="Not Concluded">Not Concluded</option>
                            <option value="Concluded">Concluded</option>
                            <option value="Impeded">Impeded</option>
                        </select>
                </td>
            </tr>   


<span id='ImpReason' style='display:none;'>This is the reason</span>

<script>
function StatusTest () {
    if (document.getElementById('cbostatus').value == "Impeded") {
        // show
        document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        // hide
        document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'none';
function StatusTest() {
  if (document.getElementById('cbostatus').options[cbostatus.selectedIndex].value == "Impeded"){

          document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'block';
  }   
  else
  {
      // hide
      document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'none';
  }
 }
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="titulos">Status:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  
  
  <SELECT class=caixas id=cbostatus style="WIDTH: 3cm;" tabIndex=25 name=cbostatus onChange= "StatusTest()">   
                            <option selected></option>
                            <option value ="Opened">Opened</option>
                            <option value= "Started">Started</option>
                            <option value ="Not Concluded">Not Concluded</option>
                            <option value ="Concluded">Concluded</option>
                            <option value= "Impeded">Impeded</option>
                        </SELECT>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            
            
<div id="ImpReason">ImpReason - hide/Show </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change onselect by `onchange`, and use `InnerText` for recover the value

```
 <SELECT class=caixas id=cbostatus style="WIDTH: 3cm;" tabIndex=25 name=cbostatus onchange= "StatusTest();">   
        <option selected></option>
        <option value "Opened">Opened</option>
        <option value "Started">Started</option>
        <option value "Not Concluded">Not Concluded</option>
        <option value "Concluded">Concluded</option>
        <option value "Impeded">Impeded</option>
    </SELECT>
```

and the function

```
function StatusTest(){
if (document.getElementById('cbostatus').options[cbostatus.selectedIndex].innerText == "Impeded"){
    // show
    document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'block';
}   
else
{
    // hide
    document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

[`here a plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/dWFcDmYVC62NyEslOC4D?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

**HTML PART**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="titulos">Status:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="caixas" id="cbostatus" style="width: 3cm;" tabIndex="25" name="cbostatus" onchange= "StatusTest();">
                <option selected></option>
                <option value="Opened">Opened</option>
                <option value="Started">Started</option>
                <option value="Not Concluded">Not Concluded</option>
                <option value="Concluded">Concluded</option>
                <option value="Impeded">Impeded</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT PART**

```
function StatusTest() {
        if (document.getElementById('cbostatus').options[cbostatus.selectedIndex].value == "Impeded") {
            // show
            document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            // hide
            document.getElementById("ImpReason").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

What I see from your code you are missing quotes("") for html attributes (e.g. id=cbostatus will be id="cbostatus", this is same for other attributes too) and for select->option you need to put a "=" sign after value, see the below change for demonstration -

Your Code:

```
<option value "Opened">Opened</option>
```

Correct Code:

```
<option value="Opened">Opened</option>
```

And this is same for all the option tag.

And yes one more thing change the html even from "oselect" to "onchange"